# Getting error "Can't convert FixNum into Array"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
class CartItemsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :initialize_cart, :check_not_signedin
    def create
        product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        kart = initialize_cart
        qty = CartItem.select(:quantity).where(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id)


        if qty == 0
            @item = CartItem.new(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id, :quantity => qty+1)
            if @item.save
                flash[:success] = "Product added"
                redirect_to category_products_path
            end
       else
            if CartItem.where("cart_id = ? AND product_id = ?", kart.id, product.id).first.update_column(:quantity, qty+1)
                flash[:success] = "Product updated"
                redirect_to category_products_path  

           end

       end
end
```

When I am trying to run this I'm getting the following error
"Can't convert FixNum into Array"
app/controllers/cart_items_controller.rb:17:in `create'

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line should return a `ActiveRecord::Relation` into `qty`:

```
qty = CartItem.select(:quantity).where(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id)
```

You should use `qty.count` instead: `qty.count == 0`

Also, you can't add a `ActiveRecord::Relation` with `1` like this: `qty+1`. It will give you the error message you had.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but I suggest you use the `debugger` gem to help you troubleshoot your problem. Follow the guide here to setup, it's very simple to setup: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debugger-gem

Then, place `debugger` in your code:

```
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    kart = initialize_cart
    qty = CartItem.select(:quantity).where(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id)
    debugger # <---- here

    if qty == 0
        @item = CartItem.new(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id, :quantity => qty+1)
        if @item.save
```

Then you can find out more while you stopped at the debugger breakpoint, you can do stuff like:

```
qty.class
qty.count
# etc
```

Also, you can run `rails console` for testing.

Comment: thanks for the info Noge, but qty.count will always return 1 if the record is present in the database for a particular cart_id and product_id. I want to fetch the number saved in quantity column for the given conditions. Any other way you could suggest?

Comment: Since you mentioned the `count` will always be `1`, then you can do `CartItem.where(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id).first.quantity` perhaps?

Comment: Have already tried it, it throws error 
"undefined method `quantity' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: That means `CartItem.where(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id).first` return `nil`. 

Thus `CartItem.where(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id).first.quantity` is equivalent to `nil.quantity`.
This explains what the error is saying, there is no defined method `quantity` for `nil`.

You need to check your `where` statement to make sure it return something before trying to access the `quantity`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the following line is returning an Array:

```
CartItem.select(:quantity).where(:cart_id => kart.id, :product_id => product.id)
```

If this is the case then you can't simply add +1 to it on this line:

```
if CartItem.where("cart_id = ? AND product_id = ?", kart.id, product.id).first.update_column(:quantity, qty+1)
```

If this is not the case, can you point out which line is number 17 as pointed out in the error message.

Comment: I think you are right, but how to fix this problem? can you suggest any other way of doing this?

Comment: You will need to handle what ever data is returned by this CartItem.select function, this could be something simple like accessing what ever is inside the array like qty[0] if there is only one element. I can only guess as to the contents so you will need to investigate qty using the inspect method perhaps.